# What does this line of Java stream mean?

Tags: java, stream

So I have this line of code. It gives me output [6,28].
Do you guys know why? I dont know what kind of numbers was someone trying to print.

```
System.out.println( IntStream.range(1,30).filter(n -> IntStream.range(1,n).filter(i->n%i == 0).sum() ==n)
               .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: It calculates the [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) between 1 and 30, all those numbers where the divisors sum to the number itself.

Comment: @KateQuinn your question provides its own examples. Read the wiki article luk provided.

Comment: In spite of the fact that it works it is a terrible way of doing it.  One clear example is it doesn't check running sums to see if the sum has exceeded the source.  Sometimes, streams are not the best solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IntStream.range(1,n).filter(i -> n % i == 0).sum() == n
```

calculates all the divisors of `n` by checking if `n` divided by the potential divisor has no remainder (`i -> n % i == 0`). All divisors are then summed and compared with `n` itself.

```
IntStream.range(1,30).filter(n -> ...).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Just does what I described above for the numbers between 1 and 30 and only keeps those where the comparison is `true`. It therefore calculates all the numbers between 1 and 30 where the divisors sum to the number itself. Those are called [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). The first two are 6 and 28, followed by 496, ...